# Generate multiple permutations of vector with non-repeating elements

Tags: r

I have a vector:

```
seq1<-c('a','b','c','b','a','b','c','b','a','b','c')
```

I wish to permute the elements of this vector to create multiple (ideally up to 5000) vectors with the condition that the permuted vectors cannot have repeated elements within the vector in consecutive elements. e.g. "abbca...." is not allowed as 'b-b' is a repeat.

I realize that for this small example there probably are not 5000 solutions. I am typically dealing with much larger vectors.    I am also willing to consider sampling with replacement, though currently I'm working on solutions without replacement.

I am looking for better solutions than my current thinking.

**Option 1. - brute force.**

Here, I just repeatedly sample and check if any successive elements are duplicates.

```
set.seed(18)
seq1b <-  sample(seq1a)
seq1b
#[1] "b" "b" "a" "a" "c" "b" "b" "c" "a" "c" "b"
sum(seq1b[-length(seq1b)]==seq1b[-1])  #3
```

This is not a solution as there are 3 duplicated consecutive elements.  I also realize that `lag` is probably a better way to check for duplicated elements but for some reason it is being finicky (I think it is being masked by another package I have loaded).

```
set.seed(1000)
res<-NULL
for (i in 1:10000){res[[i]]<-sample(seq1a)}
res1 <- lapply(res, function(x) sum(x[-length(x)]==x[-1]))
sum(unlist(res1)==0) #228
```

This produces 228 options out of 10000 iterations.  But let's see how many unique ones:

```
res2 <- res[which(unlist(res1)==0)]
unique(unlist(lapply(res2, paste0, collapse="")))  #134
```

Out of 10000 attempts we only get 134 unique ones from this short example vector.

Here are 3 of the 134 example sequences produced:

```
# "bcbabcbabca" "cbabababcbc" "bcbcababacb"
```

In fact, if I try over 500,000 samples, I can only get 212 unique sequences that match my non-repeating criteria.  This is probably close to the upper limit of possible ones.

**Option 2. - iteratively**

A second idea I had is to be more iterative about the approach.

```
seq1a
table(seq1a)
#a b c 
#3 5 3
```

We could sample one of these letters as our starting point.  Then sample another from the remaining ones, check if it is the same as the previously chosen one and if not, add it to the end.  And so on and so forth...

```
set.seed(10)
newseq <- sample(seq1a,1)  #b
newseq #[1] "b"

remaining <-seq1a[!seq1a %in% newseq | duplicated(seq1a)]
table(remaining)
#a b c 
#3 4 3 

set.seed(10)
newone <- sample(remaining,1) #c

#check if newone is same as previous one.
newone==newseq[length(newseq)] #FALSE
newseq <- c(newseq, newone) #update newseq
newseq #[1] "b" "c"

remaining <-seq1a[!seq1a %in% newseq | duplicated(seq1a)] #update remaining
remaining
table(remaining)

#a b c 
#3 4 2
```

This might work, but I can also see it running into lots of issues - e.g. we could go:

```
# "a" "c" "a" "c" "a" "b"  ...
```

and then be left with 3 more 'b's that cannot go at the end as they'd be duplicates.

Of course, this would be a lot easier if I allowed sampling with replacement, but for now I'm trying to do this without replacement.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `iterpc` package to work with combinations and iterations. I hadn't heard of it until trying to answer this question so there might also be more effective ways to use the same package.

Here I've used `iterpc` to set up an iterator, and `getall` to find all combinations of the vector based on that iterator. This seems to just report unique combinations, making it a bit nicer than finding all combinations with `expand.grid`.

```
#install.packages("iterpc")
require("iterpc")

seq1 <- c('a','b','c','b','a','b','c','b','a','b','c')

I <- iterpc(n = table(seq1), ordered=TRUE)

all_seqs <- getall(I)

# result is a matrix with permutations as rows:
head(all_seqs)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11]
#[1,] "a"  "a"  "a"  "b"  "b"  "b"  "b"  "b"  "c"  "c"   "c"  
#[2,] "a"  "a"  "a"  "b"  "b"  "b"  "b"  "c"  "b"  "c"   "c"  
#[3,] "a"  "a"  "a"  "b"  "b"  "b"  "b"  "c"  "c"  "b"   "c"  
#[4,] "a"  "a"  "a"  "b"  "b"  "b"  "b"  "c"  "c"  "c"   "b"  
#[5,] "a"  "a"  "a"  "b"  "b"  "b"  "c"  "b"  "b"  "c"   "c"  
#[6,] "a"  "a"  "a"  "b"  "b"  "b"  "c"  "b"  "c"  "b"   "c"
```

The `rle` function tells us about consecutive values equal to each other in a vector. The `lengths` component of the output tells us how many times each element of `values` is repeated:

```
rle(c("a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "b"))

# Run Length Encoding
#   lengths: int [1:3] 2 3 1 1
#   values : chr [1:3] "a" "b" "c" "b"
```

The length of `values` or `lengths` will be equal to the length of the original vector only for combinations which have no consecutive repeats.

You can therefore apply `rle` to each row, calculate the length of `values` or `lengths` and keep rows from `all_seqs` where the calculated value is the same as the length of `seqs1`.

```
#apply the rle function 
all_seqs_rle <- apply(getall(I), 1, function(x) length(rle(x)$values))

# keep rows which have an rle with a length equal to length(seq1)
all_seqs_good <- all_seqs[which(all_seqs_rle == length(seq1)), ]
```

`all_seqs_good` has an `nrow` of 212, suggesting that you did indeed find all possible combinations for your example vector.

```
nrow(all_seqs_good)
# 212
```

Technically this is still brute forcing (except that it doesn't calculate every possible combination - only unique ones), but is fairly quick for your example. I'm not sure how well it will cope with larger vectors yet...

**Edit:** this does seem to fail for larger vectors. One solution would be to break larger vectors into smaller chunks, then process those chunks as above and combine them - keeping only the combinations which meet your criteria.

For example, breaking a vector of length 24 into two vectors of length 12, then combining the results can give you 200,000+ combinations which meet your critera and is pretty quick (around 1 minute for me):

```
# function based on the above solution
seq_check <- function(mySeq){
I = iterpc(n = table(mySeq), ordered=TRUE)
all_seqs <- getall(I)
all_seqs_rle <- apply(getall(I), 1, function(x) length(rle(x)$values))
all_seqs_good <- all_seqs[which(all_seqs_rle == length(mySeq)), ]
return(all_seqs_good)
}

set.seed(1)
seq1<-sample(c(rep("a", 8), rep("b", 8), rep("c", 8)),24)

seq1a <- seq1[1:12]
seq1b <- seq1[13:24]

#get all permutations with no consecutive repeats
seq1a = apply(seq_check(seq1a), 1, paste0, collapse="")
seq1b = apply(seq_check(seq1b), 1, paste0, collapse="")

#combine seq1a and seq1b: 
combined_seqs <- expand.grid(seq1a, seq1b)
combined_seqs <- apply(combined_seqs, 1, paste0, collapse="") 

#function to calculate rle lengths
rle_calc <- function(x) length(rle(unlist(strsplit(x, "")))$values)

#keep combined sequences which have rle lengths of 24
combined_seqs_rle <- sapply(combined_seqs, rle_calc)
passed_combinations <- combined_seqs[which(combined_seqs_rle == 24)]

#find number of solutions
length(passed_combinations)
#[1] 245832
length(unique(passed_combinations))
#[1] 245832
```

You might need to re-order the starting vector for best results. For example, if `seq1` in the above example had started with "a" eight times in a row, there would be no passing solutions. For example, try the splitting up solution with `seq1 <- c(rep("a", 8), rep("b", 8), rep("c", 8))` and you get no solutions back, even though there are really the same number of solutions for the random sequence.

It doesn't look like you need to find every possible passing combination, but if you do then for larger vectors you'll probably need to iterate through `I` using the `getnext` function from `iterpc`, and check each one in a loop which would be very slow.

Comment: Thanks- this is very interesting.   You're right, this is to produce a sample of potential sequences, ideally 10,000 to be able to do a randomization test.  I don't need all solutions.    Could you explain a bit more about the "You might need to re-order the starting vector for best results. For example, if seq1 in the above example had started with "a" eight times in a row, there would be no passing solutions." - I'm not quite sure what you mean here?

Comment: Also, I guess how to split the original sequence up is very critical if what I'm after is to produce a representative sample of 10,000 sequences.  I could end up getting a very skewed distribution if I rely on performing the original sampling (i.e. splitting the original sequence in 2 or 3) only once.

Comment: @jalapic I mean that if you break a vector of 24 items into the first and last 12 items, you can end up with very few or no solutions if one of the halves had many of the same item. For example, the solution I gave of breaking the sequence into 1:12 and 13:24 is fine with the random sequence of "a", "b", and "c", but if you make `seq1 <- c("a", a", a", a", a", a", a", a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", )` you get no solutions with that method, even though there are actually lots for the original sequence of 24.

Comment: @jalapic yes you could potentially end up with some bias if that's possible for your real data, depending on how complex it is. If you need to split a larger vector you might like to re-order the vector a few times and combine solutions from multiple re-orderings. Switching the order of`seq1a` and `seq1b` in `expand.grid` could also give you extra solutions and might reduce some of the bias.

Answer (score 2):

Here another solution. Please see the comments in the code for an explanation of the algorithm.
In a way, it's similar to your second (iterative) approach, but it includes

1. a `while` loop that ensures that the next element is valid
2. and a stopping criterion for the case when the remaining elements would necessarily form an invalid combination

The algorithm is also quite efficient with longer `seq1` vectors as given in one of your comments. But I guess it's performance will degrade if you have more unique elements in `seq1`.

Here  the code:
First a few definitions

```
set.seed(1234)
seq1=c('a','b','c','b','a','b','c','b','a','b','c')

#number of attempts to generate a valid combination
Nres=10000

#this list will hold the results
#we do not have to care about memory allocation
res_list=list()
```

Now generate the combinations

```
#the outer loop creates the user-defined number of combination attempts
for (i in 1:Nres) {
  #create a "population" from seq1
  popul=seq1
  #pre-allocate an NA vector of the same length as seq1
  res_vec=rep(NA_character_,length(seq1))
  #take FIRST draw from the population
  new_draw=sample(popul,1)
  #remove draw from population
  popul=popul[-match(new_draw,popul)]
  #save new draw
  res_vec[1]=new_draw

  #now take remaining draws
  for (j in 2:length(seq1)) {
    #take new draws as long as
    #1) new_draw is equal to the last draw and
    #2) as long as there are any valid elements left in popul
    while((new_draw==res_vec[j-1])&any(res_vec[j-1]!=popul)) {
      #take new draw
      new_draw=sample(popul,1)
    }
    #if we did not find a valid draw break inner loop
    if (new_draw==res_vec[j-1]) {
      break
    }
    #otherwise save new_draw ...
    res_vec[j]=new_draw
    #... and delete new draw from population
    popul=popul[-match(new_draw,popul)]
  }
  #this is to check whether we had to break the inner loop
  #if not, save results vector
  if (sum(is.na(res_vec[j]))==0) res_list[[length(res_list)+1]]=res_vec
}
```

Now let's check the results

```
#for each result vector in res_list:
#1) check whether all subsequent elements are different ---> sum(x[-1]==x[-length(x)])==0
#2) and whether we have the same number of elements as in seq1 ---> all.equal(table(x),table(seq1),check.attributes=FALSE)
sum(sapply(res_list,function(x) (sum(x[-1]==x[-length(x)])==0)&all.equal(table(x),table(seq1),check.attributes=FALSE)))
#6085

#the previous number should be the same as the length of res_list
length(res_list)
#6085

#check the number of unique solutions
length(unique(res_list))
#212
```

Answer (score 1):

The speed of your actual job will depend on a lot of factors (e.g. how many possible passing combinations exist), but I think you can accomplish this relatively quickly by using 2 loops (similarly to how you outlined, but possibly quicker):

1. Permutate your set of variables and check that there are no
   sequential values.
2. Assess whether the passing permutation is unique to those that have already been chosen

In the following example, you set two values to control the searching process: `nsuccess` - Desired number of many unique permutations; `nmax` - Maximum number of permutations (sets upper limit on computation time)

#### Example

```
seq1 <- c('a','b','c','b','a','b','c','b','a','b','c')
seq1

set.seed(1)
nsuccess <- 200
nmax <- 30000
res <- matrix(NA, nrow=length(seq1), ncol=nsuccess)
i <- 1
j <- 1
while(i <= nsuccess & j <= nmax){
  s1 <- sample(seq1)
  s1str <- paste(s1, collapse=",")
  test <- rle(s1)$lengths
  if(sum(test) == length(test)) { # check that no values are consecutive
    U <- unique(apply(res, 2, function(x){paste(x, collapse=",")}))
    if(!s1str %in% U){ # check if new permutation is unique
      res[,i] <- s1
      i <- i+1
    }
  }
  j <-j+1
}
print(paste("i =", i, "; j =", j))
res # view the unique permutations
```

Comment: I like the neatness and logic behind this.  It seems to work very well for finding permuted sequences for relatively short vectors.  However, if the original sequence becomes quite large e.g. `seq1 <- c('a','b','c','b','a','b','c','b','a','b','c','a','c','b','a','c','a','b','a','b','c','b','c','a')`  then it is quite inefficient as too often the permuted sequence has a repeated element.

Comment: You're right - In that case, you may need to focus your efforts on a replacement function for `sample`.