# Randomly permute non-repeating sequences

Tags: c++, r, algorithm

A year ago I asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30564738/generate-multiple-permutations-of-vector-with-non-repeating-elements) in the R forum regarding how to permute a sequence 1000s of times but never allowing for repeated elements.  It is still the case that any solution in R is far too slow for my needs.

The problem is like this:

For a sequence where every letter is a separate element, e.g.

```
"...IDPGCGDCIDPGCGCDIDPGCGDCPGCIDPFJAIAHAHAHABAHAHABKPGCPGCGCECDGCPGCGCIDIPFCPGEPAJIAEPGCECJIPGCGPGCGCGADPDJDPGCPCPGCDIPEPGCJAJMAHZABAHAHAHABHAHBKRZALOBKAHABKLAHAHAHABKLKLAKLBKABABLAHAHABKBKLOKIABKLAHAHABKLABKALKABKLKAHBAKLABKBAHABLALKABABJLKAKLKHABKCRAHAKLKAKLABKLKLBKAHAKLKECECGDCGECGEDGCDGDGECECEGDCACACAHABABCDCHAHBKCQGCGCQCQGCQCGCACACBKCDCAHACQGCPGCDACAPCQAHAHBKACHAHAHBABCGCGCAHAHAMHMABAHAKLABKCPCFCABCQCQGCGCABHAHANBKQAHAHANANABKLABAKLPCGCGCPCAHABAHAHAHAHANBKALCQCGCECAHABANAHBKAKBKAHABAHBKALBHAHABKLKCPCECALCGCAKPHBAHAHAHAHAHAHABAHAHBKAMJABAHBAHAHBKALKABKPCQBANAHANHABKHBALAHALAHANBANBHABKAHANHAHABKAHAHAHAHAMANIAHABANHABABKBKLHLKLBKLKBKBKBALAHAKLBKLBHKBABHAMABKZAHAHABLKAHABAKABKOKHAKAHAHBKAHAHAHABKLHAHBKAHABKLAHAHABKAIAIAHABKLBAIAIKLKLAHAH..."
```

I need to permute (randomly shuffle) this sequence 10000 times.The original sequence never has any repeated elements.  The randomly sampled sequences need to have the same proportion of elements as the original sequence but also have no repeated elements.  Sequences may be up to 50,000 elements long.  The total number of each element looks something like this:

```
 A    B    C    D    E    F    G    H    I    J    K    L    M    N    O    P    Q    R    Z 
6537 3156 1736  198  445  138 1129 3849  818  287 2339 1190  275 1035  222  484  242  338   59
```

I have tried using `R` to solve this problem. Everything tried is too slow and also not very good at finding non-repeated elements.  I do not know `C++` that well, but would be interested in trying to utilize that through `Rcpp` to get a solution that works.

I thought this would be an interesting problem and will add a bounty for it when allowed.

A sample long sequence is [available here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jalapic/9f65738271dc86a5541f4d3ff843cb6a/raw/2098f6aeb3c016653552b11056ee22ef52ef6acb/seq).

Comment: You should clarify what you mean by "repeated element" . It seems from your old question that you don't want identical consecutive elements.

Comment: @Jarod42 yes, non-repeating means that two successive elements cannot be the same.   ABABAB is ok - AABCDE is not.

Comment: Is it necessary that each possible sequence that meets the criteria has an equal probability of being generated? Seems like the answer is yes, but you don't explicitly say so.

Comment: @samgak I'm not 100% sure of the question. I think you're asking that any potential solution ought to be equally likely to occur - if so, the answer is yes.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm asking. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to build the sequence one element at at time by adding new elements at random positions, instead of choosing each element in order.

Use the following algorithm:

- Randomly permute the list without the non-repeating constraint in order to get a random order in which to insert the elements. Call this list `a`.
- Begin with an empty list `b`.
- For each element `e` in `a`:

  - Set `attempts` to zero
  - While `attempts` < `max_attempts`:

    - Select a random position `p` from `0` to `b.size()`, with 0 meaning before the first element and `b.size()` meaning after the last element, and check if it is possible to insert `e` at this position without causing a repeat. If possible then insert `e` into `b` at position `p`, otherwise increase `attempts` and try again
  - If no element was inserted in `max_attempts` attempts, start all over again from scratch

I can't prove this is will produce a uniform distribution, but I think it will be free from any biases that will cluster certain elements towards the start or end of the sequence, where the possibilities become more determined using the sequential methods. It's possible for it to fail (e.g. if identical elements are selected for the first and second elements to insert) but this is inexpensive while `b` is short and becomes less likely the longer it gets (assuming a frequency distribution similar to the one you have shown us). OTOH, you could easily come up with a pathological distribution that would cause it to fail (e.g. 10000 As and 10000 Bs, and no other letters).

This can be implemented in linear time in C++ using an stl list for list `b`, and an array of iterators referencing each of the elements in the list. When adding a new element, add an iterator pointing to that element to the end of the array. To select a random position in the list, randomly select one of the iterators from the array.

Comment: Thank you. This is a more thought out and complete version of something I was thinking about (trying to place left-over elements randomly). The major issue with the sequences that I am using is trying to keep the distribution uniform and not clustering the most common elements at the tail of the sequence.  I will try this in C++ - thanks.